# how can i get the url link in outlook email body message using PHP

Tags: php, regex, imap

Hi i have this imap outlook mail body message. I want to get only the URL link in the body message. I am looking for a correct regex on it. Here is the body message coming from the outlook mail that I fetch using imap PHP

```
*** External Email - Caution *= **
3D"Thomson

Sender: sample.com
Recipient: sample.com
Upload Date: 2021-07-09 01:16:08.0


From:
Subject: AW-1339
Message:

Use the following links to download your file(s).

https://thomsonreuters.sendthisfile.com/sample

Note: These files will expire in 4 days from the time this email was genera= ted.
```

can someone help me figured this thing out using correct regex on it? any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: Is the link always by itself on a separate line? If so, just look for a line which starts with http ...Have you worked with regular expressions before? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: i already sove it and test it in https://regex101.com/

Comment: That's great. Please then post your solution in the answer box below so that others may benefit (and you can enhance your reputation here) :-)

Comment: solution answer is [a-z]+://\S+

Comment: Please add it as an **answer**. Comments cannot receive reputation points, and they are not searchable. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer . Thanks :-)

Comment: Also, you need to decide your quoted printable decoding.